# How to create a function that can replace a parameter?

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
let model = MyModel()

//1
guard let output = try? model.prediction (weigth:valueWeight) else {
  fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
}
//2
let length = output.length as Double
```

This code is executed hundreds of times with different parameters.

I would like to convert it into a function.

But this is the problem. Look at the lines //1 and //2. These lines have this `weigth` parameter but if this code will be generic and repeated for other cases, this parameter will have to be `depth` or `length` in other cases.

How do put this inside a function with headers that can replace these fields?

something like

```
func predict (model:MLModel, columnName:String, value:Double, target:String) -> Double {
  guard let output = try? model.prediction (columnName:value) else {
    fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
  }
  return output.target as Double
}
```

My problem here is `columnName` that is not a variable but rather a column name.

Objective-C has this `NSSelectorFromString` where a selector can be built by a string. This is the case here. I need something like "ParameterFromString".

This is how I indent do call the function:

```
let predictLength = predict(model, "weigth", 10, "length")
let predictColor = predict(model2, "hue", 19, "color")
```

I want the first line to execute

```
guard let output = try? model.prediction (weigth:10) else {
  fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
}
let length = output.length as Double
```

and the second line to execute like

```
guard let output = try? model2.prediction (hue:19) else {
  fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
}
//2
let color = output.color as Double
```

Comment: What's the source code of `MyModel`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean with `columnName` here, wouldn't `prediction(weight:)`, `prediction(height:)` etc be different functions to be called?

Comment: You're asking us about how you can better use the interface of `MyModel`, without showing us the interface of `MyModel`, lol

Comment: I have rewritten the question, adding more info. `MyModel` carries the following input weigth and output equal to length. The color model input is hue and output is color.

Comment: You still haven't told use about the `MyModel` api...

Comment: what do you want to know about `MyModel`? It is just a CoreML model I have created.

Comment: You might be able to use `KeyPath`'s

Comment: What functions it has, what their names are, what their types are, their return types... the API.

Comment: What is this `model.prediction (weigth:10)`? What `prediction` looks like? Common, help yourself and give us details to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use closures if I understand you correctly.

```
typealias Predict = (MyModel, Int) throws -> Double

let predictHeigt: Predict = {m, h in
    let output = try m.prediction(height:h)
    return output.length as Double
}

let predictHue: Predict = {m, h in
    let output = try m.prediction(weight:h)
    return output.color as Double
}
//and so on for each type of prediction

func prediction(_ p: Predict, model:MyModel, value: Int) throws -> Double {
    return try p(model,value)
}
```

And use it like

```
let height = try prediction(predictHeigt, model: model, value: 10)
let hue = try prediction(predictHue, model: model2, value: 19)
```

Comment: This seems like a crutch for bad API design in `MyModel`. It works, but it would be much better if `MyModel` was fixed instead, to address the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I add another way which demonstrates swift can also use  `NSSelectorFromString` by its own way. @objc is important and cannot be left out in most cases. Also, the objc did not support `throws`, so don't use it.

I think this is the exact way matching your original idea.

```
            class MyModel: NSObject{

            @objc func prediction(_ : Any, weight: Double) -> Predict {
                let p =  Predict()
                p["length"] = weight
                print(p)
                return p
            }
            @objc  func prediction(_ : Any, hue : Double ) -> Predict {
                let p =  Predict()
                p["color"] = hue
                return p
            }
        }

        class Predict: NSObject{
             @objc var length: Double = 0.0
             @objc var color : Double = 0.0
             subscript (_ sub : String) -> Any? {
                get{
                    return value(forKey: sub)}
                set{
                    setValue(newValue, forKey: sub)
                }
            }
        }


        class TempTests: XCTestCase {

        func predict(_ model: MyModel, _ columnName : String, _ value:Double, _ target:String) throws -> Any? {
            let sel = Selector("prediction:"+"\(columnName)"+":")
            guard let output = model.perform(sel, with: value)?.takeUnretainedValue() as? Predict else {
                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")}
            return output[target]
        }

        func testExample() {


        let model = MyModel()
        let model2 = MyModel()

        do{
            let predictLength = try predict(model, "weight", 10, "length")
            let predictColor = try predict(model2, "hue", 19, "color")
            print(predictColor!)
            print(predictLength!)
        }
        catch{
            fatalError()
                }

            }

        }
```